# What is the point of sending timeouts to a different queue and host in nservicebus?

Tags: timeout, msmq, nservicebus

I notice the default config/recommendation of the timoutmanager is running it in its own host and pointing to its own queue.

Is it simply for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout manager can manage timeouts for many different nsb endpoint hence the need to run in a separate process. This will also give you fault tolerance for your timeouts